# Can outer star be captured by a more distance galaxy due to dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter, galaxy-rotation-curve

Imagine of an outer star lies between 2 galaxy cores with identical matter & dark matter distribution. If the outer star lies closer to galaxy core 1 and farther to galaxy core 2, the dark matter volume from galaxy core 2 is larger, so this outer star can be captured by galaxy core 2. After some time, the distance is reversed, than this outer star will be recaptured by galaxy core 1. Is this observed in astronomy ?
What I have in mind is that global physics theory can't be applied here, because more distance galaxy will have more pulling effect than the closer galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be the case. The dark matter is distributed so that (approximately) the tangential orbiting speed of a star would be constant. That means that the centripetal inwards force
$$\frac{mv^2}{r} \propto \frac{1}{r}\ .$$

Hence the force on the star decreases as it gets further away from the centre of either galaxy.